# group category specific bars and provide xtics subcategory in gnuplot

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot, bar-chart

I need to plot data of three categories:

- cat1 (with subcategories i1,i2,i3)
- cat2 (with subcategories p1,p2,p3)
- cat3 (with subcategories n1,n2,n3)

Each category should be grouped and colored differently. In each group, we need to assign different patterns to boxes and corresponding subcategory as xtic label for it need to be provided for distinguishing.

Here is the sample data and the code.
Sample data: sample.dat

```
cat1 i1 95.2162 0.817947 i2 96.2065 0.710029 i3 98.4846 0.58444 
cat2 p1 96.899 0.502756 p2 97.9695 1.16202 p3 99.631 0.0911258 
cat3 n1 99.4709 0.318714 n2 99.5897 0.234542 n3 99.9535 0.0507579
```

Code:

```
set terminal png
set output 'bar.png'
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set style histogram errorbars lw 3
plot 'sample.dat' using 3:4:xtic(2) title "cat1", \
     ''             using 6:7:xtic(5) title "cat2", \
     ''             using 9:10:xtic(8) title "cat3"
```

please find the graph output. Required output is to have grouped bars in one single color and within need to have specific subcategory as xtic labels. But output here failed and showing 3 colors in all categories and only last xtic  came for each group. Can you please help me in understanding where I went wrong ? [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the `with boxes` plotting style to generate individual groups and then superimpose the errorbars. The script below sets the boxwidth to 1 and then offsets individual groups by fixed amount (4 and 8). Since there are only 3 boxes within each group, this provides sufficient "gap" between groups (as wide as each box).

```
$DATA <<EOD
cat1 i1 95.2162 0.817947 i2 96.2065 0.710029 i3 98.4846 0.58444 
cat2 p1 96.899 0.502756 p2 97.9695 1.16202 p3 99.631 0.0911258 
cat3 n1 99.4709 0.318714 n2 99.5897 0.234542 n3 99.9535 0.0507579
EOD

set terminal pngcairo enhanced rounded font ",16"
set output 'fig.png'

set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 1.0

set linetype 42 lw 2 lc rgb 'black'
set yr [94:102]

set xtics out nomirror

plot \
  $DATA using (0 + $0):3:xtic(2) w boxes lc rgb 'red' t 'cat1', \
  $DATA using (0 + $0):3:4 w yerrorbars lt 42 t '', \
  $DATA using (4 + $0):6:xtic(5) w boxes lc rgb 'green' t 'cat2', \
  $DATA using (4 + $0):6:7 w yerrorbars lt 42 t '', \
  $DATA using (8 + $0):9:xtic(8) w boxes lc rgb 'blue' t 'cat3', \
  $DATA using (8 + $0):9:10 w yerrorbars lt 42 t ''
```

This gives:
[image]

EDIT:

From your comment, it seems that I misunderstood your question. In order to group the boxes "per each row", you could do for example:

```
$DATA <<EOD
cat1 i1 95.2162 0.817947 i2 96.2065 0.710029 i3 98.4846 0.58444 
cat2 p1 96.899 0.502756 p2 97.9695 1.16202 p3 99.631 0.0911258 
cat3 n1 99.4709 0.318714 n2 99.5897 0.234542 n3 99.9535 0.0507579
EOD

set terminal pngcairo enhanced rounded font ",16"
set output 'fig.png'

set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 1.0

set linetype 42 lw 2 lc rgb 'black'
set yr [94:102]

set xtics out nomirror

set lt 1 lc rgb 'red'
set lt 2 lc rgb 'blue'
set lt 3 lc rgb 'green'


plot \
  $DATA using (4*$0):3:($0+1):xtic(2) w boxes lc variable t 'cat1', \
  $DATA using (4*$0):3:4 w yerrorbars lt 42 t '', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 1):6:($0+1):xtic(5) w boxes lc variable t '', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 1):(1/0):($0+2) w boxes lc variable t 'cat2', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 1):6:7 w yerrorbars lt 42 t '', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 2):9:($0+1):xtic(8) w boxes lc variable t '', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 1):(1/0):($0+3) w boxes lc variable t 'cat3', \
  $DATA using (4*$0 + 2):9:10 w yerrorbars lt 42 t ''
```

Here, the idea is that the boxes corresponding to the rows of the first batch of columns are placed at positions `0, 4, 8`, the boxes corresponding to rows of the second batch at positions `1, 5, 9`, and finally the third batch at `2, 6, 10`. This effectively creates the grouping `i1,i2,i3`, `p1,p2,p3`, and `n1,n2,n3`. The style `lc variable` ensures that each row gets a distinct color. However, without any adjustment, the bars in the legend would all have the same color (since the first row always corresponds to the group `i1,i2,i3`). To fix this, the script uses:

```
$DATA using (4*$0 + 1):6:($0+1):xtic(5) w boxes lc variable t '', \
$DATA using (4*$0 + 1):(1/0):($0+2) w boxes lc variable t 'cat2'
```

Here, the first statement does the plotting, while the second one generates an empty plot (due to the undefined value `1/0`), but uses a color index shifted by 1, i.e., `($0+2)` instead of `($0+1)`. This achieves that the item in the legend will get the right color (blue instead of red).

The result:
[image]

Finally, the statement `$DATA` denotes a data block. Older versions of Gnuplot (older than 5 I guess) do not support this feature so you could replace `$DATA` with a variable containing the name of the file containing the data.

EDIT2:

To be more specific, for example the expression `(4*$0 + 1):6:($0+1):xtic(5)` requests to generate boxes at x-coordinates calculated as 4 times the row number (0-based) plus 1. The height of the boxes is taken from column 6, the color index `($0+1)` is calculated as one plus the row number, and finally the xtic labels are loaded from column 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering !! But the issue here is i1,i2,i3 belongs to one category. similarly p1,p2,p3 belongs to one category and n1,n2,n3 belongs to one category.  Essentially each row is of different category. Also can you please help me in compiling the same ? $ is shown as invalid command when i m compiling

Comment: @ksn I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: can you please help in understanding this format (4*$0 + 1):(1/0):($0+3):xtic(5) what essentially are these parameters x:y:z or x:yz:p in general ?

Comment: Also I tried with gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 7. Its not recognizing colors and the line types also got changed. I tried with gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6 as such it also messed up with the format. Coud you please let me know which version did you choose for compiling ?

Comment: @ksn originally, I made the figures with Gnuplot 5.2 (patchlevel 3). However, I tried with 5.0.7 as well and the output seems to be consistent. How exactly were the colors not recognized?

Comment: @ksn as for the expression `(4*$0 + 1):(1/0):($0+3):xtic(5)`, I included a short explanation in the answer...

Comment: I tried modifying the plot to use patterns instead of colors in the boxes. I couldn't find "box pattern variable" to fill with different patterns for each row which can suffice the purpose of "lc variable" in the above plot. Can you please help how to proceed if I need to remove colors and place patterns instead.